# Is it possible to include the originator on a trigger?

Tags: pusher

As per the docs, client events are not delivered to the originator of an event. Is it possible to change this behaviour so that 1 client can send an event and all clients (including the originator) receive it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't available natively as part of the pusher-js library. Normally the originator of the event would probably just call the function that handles the event after triggering it:

```
function doTrigger( data ) {
  var triggered = pusherInstance.trigger( 'private-channelName', 'eventName', data );

  if( triggered ) {
    handleTriggeredEvent( data );
  }
}

function handleTriggeredEvent( data ) {
  // Update UI
}
```

Alternatively you could manipulate the pusher-js library and change the trigger method to also emit the event on the channel. That way the event originators event handler will also be invoked.

To be honest, this suggestion is probably going to be a bit of a hack (you'd probably need to update the `EventDispatcher` object) so I think the earlier suggestions is the best solution.